# Adding custom toolbar and docking your app to Lync Client main window

Tags: lync-2010

I looked over the internet to find out how to add a custom toolbar to Lync client main window as well as to doc my web application to the main window when it triggered by a button on the custom toolbar.
I couldn't find how to implement the functionality, although I could find on youtube Avaya and  prairieFyre presentations of their client side with custom toolbars and docked application, so I assume it is doable.

Could somebody refer me to where I can find some info on how to implement that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, but not supported by Microsoft. I'd imagine it's done by using Win32 calls to find the Lync windows, and the calling SetParent on your own window to tie the two together - but I haven't tried it.

For a list of supported extensibility points, take a look at [this post](https://blog.chimusoftware.com/post/overview-lync-apis/)